# Displaying polygon big data on a map with Python (Folium)

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I want to plot around 90.000 polygon data (~250MB GeoJSON file) on Python. I tried to plot it with Folium, but it's really computationally heavy (CPU load and out of memory problem).

I also tried to rasterize the polygon into one image but I can't fit it well on the Folium map.

How can I plot polygon big data that can reduce the computation load?